# Unable to identify the cause of error "The file is being used by another process"

Tags: c#, screenshot, ioexception

Here is the c# code:

Program.cs

```
string path = @"E:\Example.txt";

if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Create(path);
}

// smtp code for sending emails
SmtpClient clientDetails = new SmtpClient();
...
MailMessage mailDetails = new MailMessage();
...
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(@"E:\Example.txt"); // Error "The process can not access the file because it is being used by another process" occurs here
mailDetails.Attachments.Add(attachment);

clientDetails.Send(mailDetails);
```

Problem: The error (The process can not access the file because it is being used by another process) occurs only when the "Example.txt" file is NOT already existing. Meaning, the error only occurs if `File.Create(path);`creates "Example.txt" file and then, smtp is supposed to send this file. So, I assume that `File.Create()` is using the file even after creation of file is completed. Please help me to prevent it from using the txt file once it is created.

Thanks in advance for all kinds of help.

Comment: This needs a [mcve].  There is far too much code here - surely you can reduce this to something simpler that also demonstrates the problem.  Do we need all of those DLL imports to reproduce the problem?  Do we need all that email code?  Is this really the smallest example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: See also : [Find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows](https://superuser.com/q/117902/388890)

Comment: About what you are trying to to: That is what most antivirus behavior analysis would flag as malware, so you should whitelist your executable before distributing it istead of trying to bypass the antivirus.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion...let me make the code more simple and see if it reproduces the problem...

Comment: After creating the file (`File.Create(path);`) youdo nothing with it, but trying to add it as attachement (`new Attachment(@"E:\Example.txt")`)   From the code you gave here, that file should still be open?   Also you maybe should have used `new Attachment(path)` ?

Comment: I am confused by two links to non-existing questions. What is the purpose for this?

Comment: I have only used the File.Create() , I didn't open the file anywhere throughout my code. new Attachment(path) also has no effect on the code. The problem persists.

Comment: File.Create() does not do what you think it does.  File.Create(path).Close() solves the problem.

Comment: Read up on File.Create and use a using statement!  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=net-5.0

Comment: Thanks, bro. File.Create(path).Close() did solve the problem.